# Multi Threading using Snowflake JDBC Driver

Tags: multithreading, session, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to execute set of sequential queries in an API using Snowflake driver. I found  abnormal behavior while performing load test on API, queries between threads are mixing and causing the sequential order missing.

Snowflake query history shows the queries across threads sharing same session. Any suggestions to restrict this behavior to ensure thread specific query execution or separate session creation for each thread?

Snowflake driver version :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.snowflake</groupId>
    <artifactId>snowflake-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I have following grants in snowflake

1. role1 has access to only warehouse1
2. role2 has access to only warehouse2

In Spring Boot API, I am calling queries sequentially as mentioned below.

```
use role ${xyz};
use warehouse ${abc};
```

when I am hitting API sequentially even though  each thread sharing same session id, queries are executing in sequential order, but when the multiple concurrent requests given to API query mix happening, hence throwing authorization error

```
use role role1 ;
use role role2;
use role warehouse1;
```

Comment: I am able to open a connection per session using multithreading in Java and Snowflake JDBC driver. Can you share a sample of your script so we can have a look?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Are you creating a connection per thread, or are you attempting to share a connection on multiple threads concurrently?

Comment: Also specify the version of the JDBC driver you're using.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel,I am using a datasource ,hence its sharing same connection across threads causing the issue,I would like to know if i can get  a session  per thread

Comment: Using a data source is not the same as using the same connection across threads **concurrently**. Generally, if you use a data source (backed by a connection pool), then you obtain a connection for a unit of work on one thread, if you have another unit of work concurrently, that should use a different connection. That after a unit of work is completed, the connection is closed (returned to the pool), and later used for another unit of work on another thread, is a different scenario, and does not involve using the connection on multiple threads **concurrently**.

Comment: In any case, you still need to provide a [mre].